# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in ... on line 17

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After migrating from localhost to webserver I'm getting this error. Maybe it could be because of the PHP version on webserver (PHP 5.2). Any ideas?

```
<?php
$servername ="";
$username ="uran";
$password ="";
$dbname ="";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE topic_key='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<strong>Príspevok č.:</strong> " . $row["id"]. "<br>"."     <strong>Napísal:</strong> " 
    . $row["name"]. "<br>". $row["topic"]."<br>" . $row["reg_date"]."<br>"."  <br><br>";
}

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: From where `$id` comes???

Comment: this page is included in page select.php where is the $id=$_GET['id'];
$_SESSION['id2'] = $id; As I said on localholhost everything worked so I dont think that the problem is in the code.

Comment: How about the `$servername`? Did you update it when you migrate it to your webserver?

Comment: yes, the problem is somewhere here while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your query fails to that `$conn->query($sql)` will return `FALSE` (see [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)).

Please add the following code to your code to get the error message:

```
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your post solved my problem. I missed one row in my database table.